# Preventing my amplifier from being fried again and using diodes

Tags: amplifier, frequency, coil, toroidal, toroid

I'm experimenting with sending different signals through different toroidal coil windings, I also place a ball compass in the center to see the type of rotation it creates.

I would like to prevent my amplifier from being **"fried" again**.

I'm thinking I need diodes between the amplifier and the coil but I'm not exactly sure how to calculate the correct values needed.  I'm also open to using a different type of setup but please know I'm limited on funds.

The reason I think diodes may help is "current passing through a diode can only go in one direction, called the forward direction. Current trying to flow the reverse direction is blocked. They're like the one-way valve of electronics"

The way I have it setup is very simple:
**signal generator(computer)** -> **amplifier output 8 ohm impedance** -> **toroidal coil**

[image: Simple circuit]

See video link to my test setup:
https://youtu.be/rPHWugUoHCs

[image]

Comment: I suggest that if you want many people to consider responding to your question that you include a photo and schematic. Not many of us are going to watch a video for you. You might also explain why diodes would help.

Comment: A diode in a series between an amplifier and a coil will probably not do you any good.  I expect your coils are simply too low impedance for your amplifier.  Your load is too much for the amplifier, causing it to overheat and die.

Comment: @Transistor ok I added why I think diodes may help and added a little workflow diagram.

Comment: @JRE so if the output impedance of the amplifier is 8 ohms how does one go about matching it to the coil so it doesn't "fry"?

Comment: A big 4 ohm resistor to limit the current without interfering with the waveform like diodes would. Most amps can drive 4 ohms reasonably well even if they are designed for 8 ohms.

Comment: @BrianDrummond what do you mean by a "Big 4 ohm resistor" the amplifier puts out 40 watts.  So I should get a 4 ohm resistor rated at 40 watts or higher?

Comment: "output impedance" has a specific technical meaning for amplifiers. Amplifiers designed to drive 8 Ohm or 4 Ohm loads do not have an output impedance of 8 ohms or 4 ohms. Their output impedance would actually be much lower than that. Audio amplifier output impedance will be much lower than the speaker impedance it is designed for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went ahead and looked at your video.

The coil you are using will look pretty much like a short circuit at audio frequencies.

You are quite simply putting too much of a load on your amplifier.

Diodes will not help.

You need a coil with far more winding on it if you want to continue using an audio amplifier to drive the coil.

---

I used [this](https://www.translatorscafe.com/unit-converter/en-US/calculator/inductor-impedance/?mobile=1) calculator to find that a 1 millihenry inductor would have an impedance of about 6 ohms at 1000 hertz.

I then used [this calculator](http://www.66pacific.com/calculators/toroid-coil-winding-calculator.aspx) to find that for the available cores on that site it would take over 1000 turns of wire on the core to reach 1 millihenry.

I don't know what core you have, but you'll have to do something like the above to figure out how many turns of wire you'll need to get an appropriate impedance from your coil.

Comment: Thanks!   I had a thought, would it be possible to connect the coil in series with a speaker (amp -> coil -> speaker). Winding a 1000 turn coil isn't the easiest thing to do but adding resistors to create the correct impedance match may be easier.  Or is my logic incorrect?

Comment: Adding a series resistor will help keep your amplifier from burning out.  It will also reduce the power to your coil.  Do you need 40 watts into the coil?  You don't need it for the compasses, but that 40 watts is what made the ball compass jump around in the center of the core.  I'm pretty sure I saw the ball compass jumping around, not merely rotating the ball.

Comment: The main thing I was trying to do was watch how the ball compass rotates in the center of the toroidal coil. I'll be willing to invest in a 100 watt amplifier if that did the trick. Just trying to avoid "frying" it. they do have some for an ok price.  https://www.amazon.com/dp/B003EH1BM2  Is impedance matching for this as simple as ohms law?